# Java Input Output Logic

Tags: java, arrays, logic

First of all, id like to thank this fourm, as I am finding myself quickly improving through all the material on this forum and all the help different members have been giving me. So this is just a big thank you for all of that. As for my question, I've been experimenting around with input out and wanted to see if this logic would work. I am trying to get the appropriate things in their appropriate array, and wanted to see if this logic would do it. **Currently (and for a while) I wont be in a place where I can access any Virtual IDE effectively so all this was kinda done on the fly using notepad, word etc.** **So don't be to hard on my syntax. What I am mostly concerned about is the logic (if it would work) and to a lesser mistake any major mistakes in code.**

Thanks alot.

So basically, the text file goes like this. Title, one line of space, then name, age and wage and the separator is the #. Then right below that, name, age and wage the separator bring # etc etc.

(pretend there was no line spaces between Bobby, Sandy, Roger, Eric and David..so pretend in the txt file they are right under each other, but there is a gap in between information and bobby.

Information

---

> Bobby#24#5.75
>
> Sandy #19#10.22
>
> Roger #27#6.73
>
> Eric#31#8.99
>
> David#12#3.50**

Here is the logic i've come up with.

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String Name [] = new String [5];
        int Age [] = new int [5] ;
        double Wage [] = new double [5];
        String Blank [] = new String [5];   

        FileReader inputfile = new FileReader (new File(info.txt));

        BufferedReader InputBuffer = new BufferedReader (inputfile);

        String Title = InputBuffer.readline (); // to get the title 

        int count = 0;

        while (InputBuffer.readline() = null) { // this while loop grabs the blank under the title 

            Blank [count] = count;

        }

        int i = 0;

        while (InputBuffer.readline() !=null)  {        

            String Getter = InputBuffer.readline (); // reads line 
            String splitup= Getter.split(#);    // splits it 

            Name [i] = splitup[i];  // puts name in this array
            Age [i] = splitup([i]  + 1); // age in this array 
            Wage [i] = splitup([i]  + 2); // wage in this array 

         }

        InputBuffer.close();
    }
}
```

Would this logic work for storing the title in the title String, the Blank line under the Blank Array, the name under the name array, age under the age array and the wage under the wage array??

Thanks alot.

P.S: Mostly concerned about the last while loop, I want to know if it will put the name in the name array, the age in the age array and the wage in the wage array.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `List<T>` instead of array.

Comment: Is this some kind of advanced Java syntax that doesn't require semicolons?

Comment: Instead of asking if "this logic would work" why not simply run it and see for yourself?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only need one while-loop. I don't understand why you have two, especially since the conditional in the first is nonsensical ( `InputBuffer.readline() = null` ).

Your loop would look something like this:

```
boolean isTitleParsed = false;
String title;
String line;
while ( (line = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null ) {

    if (!isTitleParsed) {
        // this is the title
        title = line;
        isTitleParsed = true;
    } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
        // this is a blank line; logic for dealing with blank lines here
        ...
    } else {
        // this is actual person data
        String[] personData = line.split("#");
        if (personData != null && personData.length == 3) {
            String name = personData[0];
            String age = personData[1];
            String wage = personData[2];
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Secondly, I think using arrays is entirely the wrong way to go. Like @AVD mentioned in his comment on the OP, `List<T>` and a POJO is probably a much better solution -- and much more extensible.

And finally: no, as you've written it, your second loop will not successfully save the name, age, and wage to the arrays. You never increment `i` and the syntax `splitup([i]  + 1)` is just wrong. (You probably meant `splitup[i+1]`.)

**Using Arrays**

If you're really stuck on using arrays to save your data, you'd have to do in something like this:

```
String[] names = new String[5];
String[] ages = new String[5];
String[] wages = new String[5];

...

int index = 0;
while ( (line = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null && index < 5) {

    if (!isTitleParsed) {
      ...
    } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
      ...
    } else {
        // this is actual person data
        String[] personData = line.split("#");
        if (personData != null && personData.length == 3) {
            String name = personData[0];
            String age = personData[1];
            String wage = personData[2];

            names[index] = name;
            ages[index] = age;
            wages[index] = wage;
            index++;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Line " + line + " is malformed and was not saved.");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice that `index` is instantiated at 0, but is incremented every time we save something to the arrays. This way `names[0]` will hold the first name, `names[1]` will hold the second, and so on.

Notice also that we save a given record's name, age, and wage all at the same index. So we could expect `names[0]` to hold "Bobby", `ages[0]` to hold "24", and `wages[0]` to hold "5.75" -- all of which are related to the same record.

Finally, the condition in the `while` loop has been amended to be `(line = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null && index < 5`. This means we'll keep looping through the lines of the file until we either run out of lines (the file ends) or our index becomes greater than 5, which is the size at which we instantiated the array. This is one reason why arrays are such a bad structure to hold this data: you have to know exactly how many records you have in your file, and you may end up not filling them all the way (you allocated too much space) or not saving some records because you have no more room to store them.

**Using POJOs**

A much better way to save the data would be to use a POJO -- a Plain Old Java Object. This kind of object is pretty much a "data holder" object.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
public class PersonData {
    private String name;
    private String wage;
    private String age;

    public PersonData() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public PersonData(String name, String wage, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wage = wage;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // ... getters and setters here
}
```

In your code, you'd replace your arrays with a `List` structure of `PersonData` objects:

```
List<PersonData> records = new ArrayList<PersonData>();
```

And in your while loop, you'd save into these objects instead of into the arrays:

```
// in the else in the while loop:
String[] data = line.split("#");
if (data != null && data.length == 3) {
    PersonData record = new PersonData(data[0], data[1], data[2]);    
    records.add(record);
} else {
    // error handling for malformed line
}
```

Now if you wanted to get data for a particular record, you'd just need to extract the PersonData object from your records list and query it:

```
// assuming the first record we scraped was "Bobby#24#5.75"
PersonData person = records.get(0);
person.getName(); // returns "Bobby"
person.getAge(); // returns 24
person.getWage(); // returns 5.75
```

Since we're using a List and not an array, we don't have to worry about knowing exactly how many records there are in the file, and we don't run the risk of losing information because we don't have anywhere to store it.

This way we can also know for certain that a name, age, and wage are all related to the same record, whereas before we were just hoping that, say, all records at index 0 in the arrays were related to the same person.

Also, if you add additional data to the records -- for example, name#age#wage#favorite food -- all you have to do is add a new field to the `PersonData` object and add a line in your parsing method to add that data to the object. If you were using arrays, you'd need to add a new array, and so on.

It's also much easier to create logic if, say, you have a row that only has a name or that missing a wage, and so on -- so that you're actually able to save the data in some meaningful fashion.

Comment: What if I had incremented i and put the splitup to the correct syntax of splitup[i+1]?? Would it have succesfully saved the information in their respective arrays then?

Comment: @user1556791 no because you never incremented `i`. It would have just saved into index 0.

Comment: @user1556791 -- I edited my post to include how to correctly use arrays in this instance, and how a POJO might be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make good progress in Java or any OOP Language for that matter you should always approach a problem in a Object Oriented Manner.

For the problem at hand you should always consider a class to store the Person Info rather than using associative arrays.

```
class PersonInfo {

 PersonInfo(String name,int age,float wage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.wage = wage;
 }

String name;
int age;
float wage;

}
```

The code is more or less the same from above...but it should give a List of PeopleInfo as output.

```
List<PersonInfo> peopleInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean isTitleParsed = false; 
while ( (line = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null ) {

    if (!isTitleParsed) {
        // this is the title
        title = line;
        isTitleParsed = true;
        continue;
    } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
        // this is a blank line; logic for dealing with blank lines here
    } else {
        String[] personData = line.split("#");
        if (personData != null && personData.length == 3) {
            peopleInfo.add(new PersonInfo(personData[0],personData[1],personData[2]));
        }

    }
```